# wso2 esb validate mediator always says the request is invalid

Tags: validation, wso2, esb, mediator, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb 4.0.3 and I have some problem in making the  mediator to work .

The problem is with the given schema, even though I send the correct soap request the validate mediator evaluates the request in invalid and so the sequence configured in the on-fail is always getting executed

```
<inSequence>   
    <validate source="$body/reg:RegistrationServiceRequest">
         <on-fail>
                <sequence key="registrationFaultSequence"/>
         </on-fail>
         <schema key="gov:com/testcompany/RegistrationWrapperAttributeTypes.xsd"/>
         <schema key="gov:com/testcompany/RegularRegistrationWrapperTypes.xsd"/>
    </validate>
    .....
</inSequence>
```

I verified the validity of soap request through SoapUI also and it says the request is valid but wso2 thinks it is invalid

Can anybody suggest whats wrong with the above configuration ?

Thanks
S

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to pin-point anything without knowing the exact reason that trigged this. However you can find more information simply by putting a "log" mediator inside the "on-fail" elements the way it is described below and get a feeling of what has really gone wrong. Please post the "output" of the log mediator so we can dig into this further.

```
<log level="custom">
   <property name="MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
</log>
```

Cheers,
Prabath

Answer (score 1):

you should declare schema before on fail and also mention the resource as well.

```
<validate cache-schema="true" description="ValidateCustomerRequest" source="//Customer:Customer" xmlns:Customer="some namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <schema key="gov:custom/Customer.xsd"/>
    <resource key="gov:custom/Customer.xsd" location="Customer.xsd"/>
    <on-fail>
        <makefault version="soap11">
            <code value="soap11Env:VersionMismatch" xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
            <reason value="Request is Invalid"/>
        </makefault>
    </on-fail>
</validate>
```